# Prolog behavior

Tags: prolog

I've been trying to learn Prolog by solving project euler. To solve problem #1, I came up with the following.

```
divides(X,Y) :- Y mod X =:= 0.

sumlist([],0).
sumlist([H|T],X) :-
    sumlist(T,Y), X is Y + H.

mult_3_or_5(X) :- between(1,999,X),
                  (divides(3,X); divides(5,X)).

find_sum(Z) :- findall(X,mult_3_or_5(X),Y),
               sumlist(Y,Z).
```

The problem with this is that it counts numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 twice. I certainly have a misunderstanding of how Prolog operates and I believe I need to use the cut operator or something like that. I would appreciate a good explanation of what's going on.

Comment: Essentially like doing a cut, since it eliminates the choice point, you could use `->` and `;`. Instead of `(... ; ...)` do, `( divides(3, X) -> true ; divides(5, X) ).`

Comment: Or use setof, that removes duplicates, instead of findall. A bit overkill though

Comment: @lurker That did work, thanks! Though I'm not quite sure how it eliminates the choice point.

Comment: @cauliflower if you look at the [documentation for the `->` operator](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,%274.8%27,swi(%27/doc/Manual/control.html%27))#send_arrow/2), it explains how it "commits" to the choice made.

Comment: Yet another approach might wrap the `divides` tests in a meta-predicate call `once`.